# How to create a method which takes generic list and string parameter with mapping?

Tags: c#

I have this C# working code now.

```
using (var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(_connectionString))
{
    bulk.DestinationTableName = "Person";
    bulk.WriteToServer(DataTableHelper.ToDataTable(persons));
}
```

The problem is that the above code only applies to one table and one list object. But I have 3 more different tables and different lists that use the same code above.

Example

| TableName | List Object |
| --- | --- |
| Person | persons |
| Address | address |
| Contact | contact |

Instead of duplicating the code 3 times, I am creating a method which takes a parameter.

How can I achieve that using a Tuple, a dictionary, or a generic, since there are only two values and map is needed?

I tried something like below but the syntax is invalid.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<T>>();
dict.Add("Person", persons);
dict.Add("Address", address);
dict.Add("Contact", contact);
```

Comment: Whether you should refactor code or not is your personal decision. So can't help you with that (and it is off-topic to ask for such opinions).

Comment: @.AlexeiLevenkov @.Zer0 @.JSteward Strange closing for opinion... (?)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The question body can be misleading as asking using english words for "a better thing" while in fact asking "how to solve a problem and tried many ways without succes"... Here, this is a real question, not opinion based at all. I updated the question to remove this "ambiguity".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `DataTableHelper.ToDataTable()` can handle a list of `Person`/`Address`/`Contact`, one way would be to create a generic method that takes the list of objects and the name of the table:

```
void WriteToServer<T>(List<T> objects, string tableName)
{
    using (var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(_connectionString))
    {
        bulk.DestinationTableName = tableName;
        bulk.WriteToServer(DataTableHelper.ToDataTable(objects));
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
WriteToServer(persons, "Person");
WriteToServer(addresses, "Address");
WriteToServer(contacts, "Contact");
```

And if `Person`, `Address`, and `Contact` share the same base type (base class or an interface), then you should add a constraint to the method:

```
void WriteToServer<T>(List<T> objects, string tableName) where T : ISomething
```

Answer (score 0):

I will illustrate the method of use with an example.The example is very simple

```
public class Person
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string PersonName { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
   public string PersonAddress { get; set; }
}
public class StoreDataBase<T>
{
   public static void ToDataTable(T item)
   {
       using (TestDBContext db = new TestDBContext())
       {
           db.GetTable<T>().InsertOnSubmit(item);
           db.SubmitChanges();
       }
   }
}

//for use
Person person = new Person() { ID = 1, PersonName = "Meysam" };
StoreDataBase<Person>.ToDataTable(person);

Address address = new Address() { PersonAddress = "Asia" };
StoreDataBase<Address>.ToDataTable(address);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I can't use Entity Framework. I need to use SqlBulkCopy, so need to pass in tablename as string